# Can't find element that exists using Python Selenium IE

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to type text in a text box

`<input name="pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente" class="number numero-utente" id="pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente" type="text" maxlength="9" value="">`

I've tried the following

`driver.find_element_by_name("pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente").send_keys('123123123')`
`driver.find_element_by_id("pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente").send_keys('123123123')`

I always get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [id="pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente"]
```

Comment: Can you check if input is not under the iframe also can you provide the URL or relevant HTML source?

Comment: How can i check if it is under the iframe? I can't provide you with the URL because it requires a log in, sorry.

Comment: At least provide the relevant HTML source, Just check in the dev tool by typing iframe in the `Element` tab and it's scope

Comment: First of all try adding some delay like `time.sleep(5)` before `driver.find_element_by_name("pesquisarUtente.numeroUtente").send_keys('123123123')`

Comment: This can be the possibility as mentioned by @Prophet

Answer (score 0):

**Try using Xpaths or Css Selectors.**

This error commonly occurs when there is more than one element with the same id so selenium is expecting find_elementS_by_id.
Xpaths and Selectors are unique to each element so they work better when trying to find a specific element.

example using xpaths:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("ENTER XPATH HERE").send_keys('123123123')`

To get the Xpath of an element you simply 1: hover over the element in the developer mode 2:right click on it 3:hover over the copy option 4:move down to copy Xpath and click

[image: How to get the Xpath of an element]

Css Selectors work the same way. (`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("SELECTOR HERE")`)
And you can see the option to copy one 3 above the option to copy the Xpath